# while convert ajax to promise I do making some mistakes

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I have a ajax code block where I try to fetch some data so I want to use new es6 approaches and convert to promise api but I dont know why I cant get result ..

```
if (term.length > 2) {
    console.info('term: ', term)
debugger;
    fetch('url' + term + ' &otherparameters etc.', {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
    })
        .then(res => res.json())
        //.then(data => console.info('ArrayOfAramaResult: ', data.ArrayOfAramaResult.AramaResult))
        .then(data => data.ArrayOfAramaResult.AramaResult, () => {
            $(searchResultsContainer).html("");
            $.each(data, function (indis, item) {

                var ekle = $('<div><a href="#">' + item.xxxxxx + ", " + item.yyyyyy + '</a></div>');
                $(searchResultsContainer).append(ekle);

                ekle.find("a").click(function () {
                    $("#search-input").val(item.xxxxxx + ", " + item.yyyyyy);
                    _zoom(item.LON, item.LAT);
                    $('#searchResults').removeClass("in");
                    return false;
                });
            });
        })
        .catch(error => console.error('Error:', error));
}
else {
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think this one is wrong

```
.then(data => data.ArrayOfAramaResult.AramaResult, () => {
```

should be written as

```
.then(successFn, failFn)
```

or

```
.then(data => {

})
.catch(err => {

})
```

Maybe you meant to write this?

```
    .then(data => data.ArrayOfAramaResult.AramaResult))
    .then(data => {
```

---

to be able to use async/await with promise just have to put all code inside of a async function

```
async function populateData() {
  var something = await promise
}
```

you can read more about async functions here
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function

So your code probably look something like this

```
const res = await fetch(url, options);
const json = await res.json();
const data = data.ArrayOfAramaResult.AramaResult;

$(searchResultsContainer).empty();

data.forEach(item => {
    var ekle = $(`<div><a href="#">${item.xxxxxx}, ${item.yyyyyy}</a></div>`);
    $(searchResultsContainer).append(ekle);

    ekle.find("a").click(function () {
        $("#search-input").val(item.xxxxxx + ", " + item.yyyyyy);
        _zoom(item.LON, item.LAT);
        $('#searchResults').removeClass("in");
        return false;
    });
});
```

and then you would call it like

```
populateData().catch(error)
```

Comment: yes it works bro thank you so if you mind can you tell me how to fetch in async await ?

Comment: PS: be careful when you add html like you do in you anchor link, it could contain html